# NTLM authentication on Exchange Server

Tags: office365, exchange-server, exchangewebservices, basic-authentication, ntlm

Currently, I am facing some uncertainties and I hope that you have some advice for me.

**The current situation**

Currently, we can access Office 365 information (such as appointments and user information) by using Microsoft Basic Authentication. This works fine for us.

**The problem**

As of 13 October 2020 Microsoft will move away from the basic authentication and they will stop supporting it. Our company decided to go with NTLM authentication. We are going to set up an Exchange Server although I have some uncertainties about this.

- Is it even possible to configure NTLM authentication on an Exchange Server?
- Would there be massive code differences after the switch to NTLM authentication? As far as I know, the way of authenticating is different (providing a domain name, username, and password)

I find the information on google very limited so I hope one of you could give me some insight on this topic.

Answer (score 1):

> As of 13 October 2020 Microsoft will move away from the basic authentication and they will stop supporting it.

This has now been delay due to Covid 19 to the second half of 2021 https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/exchange-team-blog/basic-authentication-and-exchange-online-april-2020-update/ba-p/1275508

> Our company decided to go with NTLM authentication. We are going to set up an Exchange Server although I have some uncertainties about this.

Why ? NTLM has all the same security issues as Basic Authentication in regards to password spray attacks and Man in the Middle attacks. Setting up a local Exchange server will mean you would have to migrate all the Mailbox back to OnPremise which isn't a trival thing to do either.

> Is it even possible to configure NTLM authentication on an Exchange Server?

By default when you setup Exchange OnPrem NTLM will be enabled on the server

> Would there be massive code differences after the switch to NTLM authentication?

Depends on the libraries your using for example in the EWS Managed API generally you don't need any change (you may need to use the down-level username format eg domain\username) . The amount of change required to Support Modern Authentication in Office365 is minor and would be a lot less then cost and effort of Migrating to Exchange OnPremise.