# how can I access exchange mailbox programatically

Tags: c#, office365

I try to read an office 365 mailbox in order to download attachments programmatically. But I only get this error...`The request failed. The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized`

I use this code...

```
static void GetInboxMail(string emailAddress, string pass)
{
    ExchangeService service = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2010_SP2);
    service.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(emailAddress, pass);

    service.Url = new Uri("https://outlook.office365.com/EWS/Exchange.asmx");

    if (service != null)
    {
        FindItemsResults<Item> result = service.FindItems(WellKnownFolderName.Inbox, new ItemView(100));

        foreach (Item item in result)
        {
            EmailMessage message = EmailMessage.Bind(service, item.Id);
            string body = message.Body.Text;
            string from = message.From.Name.ToString();
            string subject = message.Subject.ToString();
            Console.WriteLine("Email Sender :" + from);
            Console.WriteLine("Email Body" + body);
            Console.WriteLine("Email Subject" + subject);
        }
    }
}
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [NTLM authentication on Exchange Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62319770/ntlm-authentication-on-exchange-server)

Comment: As of the first of october 2022 windows will disable basic auth : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/clients-and-mobile-in-exchange-online/deprecation-of-basic-authentication-exchange-online So you might want to look into https://github.com/jstedfast/MailKit/blob/master/ExchangeOAuth2.md#register-your-application-with-microsoft

Comment: Also note that [Microsoft writes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/clients-and-mobile-in-exchange-online/deprecation-of-basic-authentication-exchange-online): "*Exchange Web Services [will] no longer receive feature updates and we recommended that application developers switch to using Microsoft Graph.*" Thus, you might want to reconsider whether you really want to write code using a technology that is being phased out.

Comment: Thanks, look complicated to get to work.... I'll try to get it working